# How to remove last decimal digit from float in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, floating-point

Say I have an arbitrary float `x = 123.123456` and want to remove the last n decimal digits from the float i.e. `n = 1` then `x = 123.12345`, `n = 2` then `x = 123.1234` and so on. How can this be achieved in python?

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe you can convert it to a string (assuming no rounding is needed) then use slicing?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, was hoping I'd find a question and answer on here, apparently not hence I asked.

Comment: This problem looks pretty complicated with floats. And perhaps even not completely well-defined. I think the first step would be to express `x` as a decimal number (floats are not decimal numbers). Perhaps this could be done with python's standard library module Decimal, or with clever use of `fractions.Fraction(x).limit_denominator()`

Comment: Do you want to change the value, or is it for representation purposes, e.g. print? Also, normally people know how many significant decimal places they want, not how many to remove from the end.

Comment: The following seems to work for floats:
float = 123.456 n = 1 str = str(float) str = str[:-n] float(str) #123.45

Comment: @MShakeG Please don't name a variable `float`. `float` is already the name of builtin class `float`. If you shadow that name by giving it to a variable, you lose access to class `float`, to the function `float` that can convert stuff to float, and it's confusing for readers who expect `float` to refer to the class rather than to a variable, and it can have unintended consequences because of the way names are dynamic rather than scoped in python.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick you are asking, but be mindful of the issues with floating point numbers.

```py
# let's cut 2 digits
n = 2

# naively we can do this
f = 123.123456
short_f = float(str(f)[:-n])

# but watch out for floating point error
f = 1.2 - 1.0  # f should be 0.2 but is actually 0.19999999999999996
short_f = float(str(f)[:-n])  # so this gives 0.199999999999999
```

This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), maybe you are looking for [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) or [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

Comment: I would upvote the answer is you highlighted the "issues with floating point numbers" a little more. Consider for instance: `f = 123.123456; for _ in range(5): f = f + 0.000001`. Now, `str(f)` is `'123.12346099999999'` instead of `'123.123461'`.

Comment: I will emphasise some more you're right.